# xpath-default-namespace: matching nodes from loaded XML without namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

I have an XML file what I want to filter by an XML file what I pass as parameter to my XSLT 2.0 file with Saxon CE's setParameter function:

```
xsltData = Saxon.requestXML("filter.xsl");
xmlData = Saxon.requestXML("xmlfile.xml");
var xsltProcessor = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xsltData); 
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "src", "filterxml.xml");
var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlData);
```

Parameter XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Items>
        <Item SrcName="itemname1" NewName="newitemname1"></Item>
        <Item SrcName="itemname2" NewName="newitemname2"></Item>
        <Item SrcName="itemname3" NewName="newitemname3"></Item>
    </Items>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.mynamespace"
                xmlns="http://www.mynamespace">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" name="xml" />

    <xsl:param name="src"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="filter-doc" select="if (doc-available($src)) then doc($src) else ()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Items" select="$filter-doc/Items"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$Items/Item"/>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is, that I have an xpath-default-namespace in the XSLT file, with this I can't access $Items/Item. 
If I add the namespace xmlns="http://www.mynamespace" to the  element everything is working fine. 
Is there a way to make this work without adding the namespace to my parameterxml?
I know that in the setParameter function the first parameter is namespace, but even if I set a namespace here nothing changes in the result.

Is there any possibility to add the namespace to $Items with XSLT?

Comment: Why do you have an an xpath-default-namespace in the XSLT file ? Your stylesheet should work without it.

Comment: Because I have a namespace in my input xmlfile, and if I don't set a namespace it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change that setting as needed: `<xsl:variable name="Items" xpath-default-namespace="" select="$filter-doc/Items"></xsl:variable>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to refer to both namespaced and non-namespaced nodes in the same XSLT then you probably shouldn't use `xpath-default-namespace`.  Instead, bind a prefix to this namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:my="http://www.mynamespace"
                exclude-result-prefixes="my"
                xmlns="http://www.mynamespace">
```

Now you can refer to nodes in the `http://www.mynamespace` namespace using `my:elementName` and bare unprefixed names will refer to nodes (such as your `Items`) that are not in a namespace.

While you *can* use different values for `xpath-default-namespace` in different parts of the document (the processor will look up the tree and use the value on the nearest ancestor it finds) this is something I would personally avoid as it is prone to break under refactoring - e.g. if you decide to extract some code from inside a template into a callable template or `xsl:function` and inadvertantly move it outside the scope of an `xpath-default-namespace`.  If you stick to prefixes declared at the top level then it is always clear which namespace you mean in which expression.

Comment: Yes, but as Martin points out, if you are dealing with multiple source documents with different default namespaces, you can juggle the xpath-default-namespace with local scope in your stylesheet to avoid using prefixes everywhere: though frankly, doing so might end up with harder-to-read code than if you use prefixes liberally.

Comment: @MichaelKay re your final sentence - that's why I usually avoid it.